# How to represent sound file as byte array in Java

Tags: java, audio

I am using some algorithms which need data represented in **array of bytes** it is no problem when I am working on text files but I don't know how to put a sound file in a that kind of array. I don't have specified extension of that sound file, so it can be whatever is the easiest. ***So: How to put a sound file to a byte array in Java?***

Thank you.

Comment: `byte[] bytes = new byte[length];`? your question isn't clear. do you not know how to create bytes array and java syntax?

Comment: What is unclear? I have a SOUND(not text) file in a specified directory and I would like to put it into array of bytes?

Comment: it wasn't clear because you mention the text file and there isn't much different between text file and any other files if you read bytes directly from text file (not using text file helper classes/tools, e.g. FileReader.

Comment: What format are you getting the sound in? The WAVE format is usually the easist to work with.

Comment: @JakubZaverka I said that i don't have specified format, I don't know which one is easiest to use? If WAVE is easiest to use I will choose wave. How to put WAVE file into byte array?

Comment: Do you need to put the sound samples into the array to process later, or do you just need to read a generic file into a bytearray?

Comment: basically, there are no different between text file and any other files . they are all stream of bytes. the only difference is in the sequence or pattern of the bytes.

Comment: @JakubZaverka I need the whole sound sample to be load into the array so it will be processed later.(It is for the performance test of other algorithm)

Comment: Without knowing the format of the sound data, there is nothing you can do. Each format saves the data differently. You can only read the raw bytes, but that is not going to tell you much - you won't be able to extract the sound from the file. How do you know the file is sound in the first place?

Comment: I meant that i don't have to use specified format(I can choose which one I will be using cause it is not the important thing). If the wave format is comfortable to use it can be wave format(I choose to use this one).

Comment: OK, then you need to know the WAVE file format. Each WAVE file must adhere to a specific format, which you can read [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat). Just a warning: the samples are rarely just bytes, they can be ints, longs, floats, doubles and you also need to account for the fact that the file can contain multiple channels.

Answer (score 3):

> So: How to put a sound file to a byte array in Java?

```
File f = new File(soundFilePath, soundFileName);
byte[] soundFileByteArray = new byte[f.length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
fis.read(soundFileByteArray);
```

Comment: Is it that simple?Don't you have to put the `read` inside a `while` in order to check whether the file ends?

Comment: @giannosfor if you allocate enough length for the array, then it reads the whole file.

Comment: @gigadot `f.length()` returns `long` while `new byte[]` expects `int`, changing it to `new byte[(int) f.length()]` is okay? since there is possibility of losing some data.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you can use Apache common IO library, the FileUtils class contains a [readFileToByteArray](https://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToByteArray%28java.io.File%29) method for reading a file into a byte array in one line:

```
byte[] bytes = FileUitls.readFileToByteArray(file);
```